# Batch ffmpeg and compress the files

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg

I am doing a bunch of conversions with `ffmpeg`, where I need to watermark the content. I am using a batch file to run the `ffmpeg` application, but I want to automate all of this.

```
for %%a in ("*.mp4*") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -i logo.png -filter_complex overlay "newfiles\%%~na.mp4"
pause
```

Source video files:

```
video_a.mp4
video_b.mp4
video_c.mp4
```

Source image files:

```
logo_x.png
logo_y.png
logo_z.png
logo_u.png
```

For every logo PNG image, `ffmpeg` should be executed for all MP4 video files.
Output should be written to a new folder named `output_folder_` + name of the logo image, for example `output_folder_logo_x`.

And as soon as converting an entire folder like the logo_x output videos finished, the produced files should be compressed into a RAR archive with using best compression into a dropbox folder like `c:/users/admin/documents/dropbox`.

This way I could automate all the conversion and upload process.

In the end I would have in my `dropbox/megaSync` folder:

```
output_folder_logo_x.rar
output_folder_logo_y.rar
output_folder_logo_z.rar
output_folder_logo_u.rar
```

UPDATED CODE:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%g in ("*.png*") do (
    echo %%~ng
    md folder_prefix_%%~ng
    for %%b in ("*.mp4*") do (
        %%~ng
        ffmpeg -i "%%b" -i %%g -filter_complex overlay "folder_prefix_%%~ng\%%~nb.mp4"
    )
)
pause
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my suggestion for the batch code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "FolderBaseName=output_folder"
set "BaseOutputFolder=%TEMP%\%FolderBaseName%"
set "DropBoxFolder=%USERPROFILE%\documents\dropbox\megaSync"
md "%DropBoxFolder%" 2>nul

for %%I in (logo_*.png) do (
    set "OutputFolder=%BaseOutputFolder%_%%~nI"
    md "!OutputFolder!" 2>nul
    for %%J in (*.mp4*) do (
        ffmpeg.exe -i "%%~fJ" -i "%%~fI" -filter_complex overlay "!OutputFolder!\%%~nJ.mp4"
    )
    %ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\Rar.exe a -cfg- -ep1 -inul -m5 "%DropBoxFolder%\%FolderBaseName%_%%~nI" "!OutputFolder!\*"
    rd /S /Q "!OutputFolder!"
)

endlocal
```

Open a command prompt window and run there:

- `for /?`
- `set /?`
- `md /?`
- `rd /?`

This results in getting help displayed for the used commands.

Comment: thank you so much, but this i am having trouble setting the dropbox folder, syntax issue i belive. set "DropBoxFolder=c://users/admin/documents/dropbox". Isnt this correct? thank you

Comment: I don't know where your DropBox folder is located on your machine. Paths on Windows have the backslash and not the forward slash as directory separator. And there should be always only 1 directory separator between each part of a path, i.e. `"DropBoxFolder=C:\users\admin\documents\dropbox"`. Whereby the provided batch code should be the same as `%USERPROFILE%` is replaced by the profile path of current user account. I'm wondering that you use an administrator account. Do you have write permission to the specified folder with the account used to run this batch file?

Comment: Thank you so much, and sorry for the late reply, finally I got this thing up and running based on your answer :) you guys are the best!

Answer (score 1):

you are almost there, create a new `FOR` loop around your existing one

so that for each png,

it will iterate over all mp4 creating the overlays in a new directory

and finally rar together all the resulting files

```
for %%a in (*.png) do (
  md "out%%~na"
  for %%b in (*.mp4) do (
    ffmpeg -i "%%a" -i "%%b" -filter_complex overlay "out%%~na\%%b"
  )
  call :dorar "out%%~na.rar" "out%%~na\*"
)
```

Comment: thank you, please have a look at my updated code, the only issue I have is that I need to rename the images like 0001.logo.png, 0002.logo.png, and I want to remove the '0001.' and the extension, just keeping the logo name to name the folder. thanks

Comment: Thaats a new question. I suggest yo accept  this answer and post as a new question.